# Connecting 1.8V USB and PCIe to 3.3V system

Tags: integrated-circuit, usb-device, pcie

I'm working with a google coral module (ASIC) that has both PCIe gen2 1x and USB 2.0. From the datasheet (https://coral.ai/docs/module/datasheet/) the I/O levels are 1.8V maximum. The problem then becomes to connect the USB 2.0 and the PCIe which instead have levels of 3.3V. How can I interface the chip with the USB and with the PCI?

Comment: Why not use a high-speed level shifter? Is there not one with the required speeds?

Comment: Did you check the specs on your mystery chip (asic) and see if its IO pins are 3.3V tolerant?

Comment: Does the chip really offer D+ and D- (just with the wrong voltage levels) or does it implement a USB transceiver interface (like ULPI)?

Comment: the chip has the D+ and D- pins with wrong voltages, I've found the MAX3344EEUE but has a low data rate (12Mbps)

Comment: @AndreaRoss I'm pretty sure that if you buy a complex chip that does PCIe and USB, they'll have some example circuit that shows how to interface to actual PCIe and USB. What does that example use? (I'm almost certain that it's pretty unlikely you'll need to do external voltage shifting for PCIe – that really makes the job of the physical PCIe endpoint on the ASIC harder, so I'm betting on a misunderstanding, or on a mislabeling by the ASIC manufacturer here). Can you link to a datasheet of said ASIC?

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is the datasheet of the asic https://coral.ai/docs/module/datasheet/ In 2.6 section it's also said that "if connected to a host with different logig levels, they must be level shifted"

Comment: @AndreaRoss Can you add type and datasheet link to the question? This seems **very** important to potential answerers, and most of them won't look for it in the comments! Please **edit** your question to include model name and datasheet link.

Answer (score 0):

So, PCIe is not 3.3V signalling at all; it's a differential, AC-coupled bus with some 0.5 Vpp or less voltage swing. There's no problem here.

USB2 Low and Full Speed indeed does signalling with a voltage higher than 1.8 V, but high speed doesn't, and I think you can [negotiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)#USB_2.0_speed_negotiation) that you do high-speed without having to support the high speed IO.

While I feel (don't actually know) that building a device that's high-speed-only isn't quite USB-specification-compatible, that doesn't matter too much for Google: their target market for the USB-connected variant clearly is embedded devices, i.e. devices where they do the Google-typical thing of not actually quite 100% implementing something so that it works out of the box, but shooting themselves in the foot by requiring the other end to employ a quirk, and having problems with that for years. In this case, it's reasonable (but bad style, in my humble opinion) to assume the host can be forced into high-speed mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite clear fromt he datasheet that they use 1.8V for all of the edge IO pins on that chip including USB. This is actually not an issue for applications where two ICs are directly connected which both support the low voltage (inter-chip USB), but won't work for an external connector.

You will therefore need a level shifter suitable for use with USB2.0 which can take 1.8V to 3.3V and vice versa. A quick Google for USB Lev shifters and [TXS0202](https://www.ti.com/product/TXS0202) is one such example, other manufacturers will likely have similar parts.